# Windows 10 indexing runs at full throttle after index rebuild finishes

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook-2007, search-indexing

I am using Windows 10 version 1703 (OS Build 1506.413) with Outlook 2007 SP3 (12.0.6770.5000)

After a recent big windows update I was forced to rebuild the Windows Search Index. While it is expected that the service will be busy while rebuilding, it has to calm down after it has finished. Alas, no, it just won't calm down. It has been more than a day now. The trouble shooter does not find any problems.

Does anyone have a solution? Any idea what this service is doing?

[image: Indexing reports that it is complete. So what is this activity?]

Resource Monitor does not show any significant disk activity:

[image: Resource Monitor shows CPU activity]

[image]

Comment: Just kill it. No harm in doing so, I've found from doing such myself.

Comment: End task it and disable the service.

Comment: Press WINDOWS+R on your keyboard, execute "perfmon.exe /res", under "Disk Activity" scroll down and look for entries of the process "SearchProtocolHost.exe" and look what the last accessed file is and whether the process keeps accessing it or not (and post it's name).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @nullterminatedstring. Resource Monitor shows almost no disk activity for SearchIndexer.exe process. Whatever it is doing, it is doing in memory.